# executing jquery functions in an ajax callback function?

Tags: jquery

```
$.ajax({


            type: "POST",
            url: "",
            data:   "callback=delete_contact_us_entry&offset=" + posts + "&numposts=" + num,
            success: function(html){
                jQuery("#output").html(html);


            }

});
```

This code would execute a callback function called delete_contact_us_entry on a file named ajax.php

What I want to do is, if successful, run a jquery function that deletes the appropriate tr tag.

Where would be the best area to place the jquery delete function? In the success:function? Can you put it in the callback function?

Also, i've tried to return a 1 or 2 depending on if the query succeeded or failed, but my if statements in the "success:function(html)" woudl not work... is it because the "html" is an object and not necessarily a variable?

Thanks

Comment: basically I have a list of contacts and if one is deleted the tr is removed... what if I just refreshed the whole table? would that be easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute things after your ajax callback has completed, you should put it into the function you are assigning as the success handler. For example:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "",
   data:   "callback=delete_contact_us_entry&offset=" + posts + "&numposts=" + num,      
   success: function(result){
       jQuery("#output").html(result);
       $("#someTable tr:first").remove();
   }
});
```

If your server side script is returning some return value and not HTML, I suggest renaming the parameter to result or something alike so that it's not so confusing. You can then use that variable inside the success function for iffing and doing different stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could place a check for the return value, and depending on that, either alert the user or remove the tr tag.

```
        success: function(html){
            jQuery("#output").html(html);

            if(html == '1') {
              // remove tr
            } else {
              alert('error');
            }
        }
```

Also add a `dataType: 'html'` to your $.ajax call, to make sure jQuery doesn't parse it as something else in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely put the delete logic inside the callback function.

As for your issue of returning 1 or 2, it should work with html as the dataType, but then you have to keep in mind that it is a string, not an int 1 or 2, so you'd have to use

```
if (html == "1")
```

rather than

```
if (html == 1) // or if (html)
```

There might also be some issues if your html contains other characters (like \n), they might interfere with your if conditionals. Take a look at ajax dataType (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you might want to consider returning a json object from your php (using json_encode) so you can have a nice object on the javascript side.

Comment: ok putting javascript in my callback and returning it would work? if I did return "$("#someTable tr:first").remove();" that would be executed as javascript and not some unreadable html?